# Limit of $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n^{1/2}}\sum_{k=0}^n(\frac{1}{2^{1/2}}(1+i))^k$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n^{1/2}}\sum_{k=0}^n(\frac{1}{2^{1/2}}(1+i))^k$

Does that series converge or diverge?
I know that the limit of $\frac{1}{n^{1/2}}$ is $0$ and $|1+i|^k \le2^k$ and $\frac{1}{2^{1/2}}$ shouldn't really matter. I guess the result is $0$ because $0 *2^k=0$ for every k. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\zeta=(1+i)/\sqrt2=\exp(\pi i/4)$. Therefore
$$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\zeta^k=\frac{\zeta^{n+1}-1}{\zeta-1}
=\frac{\exp(\pi i(n+1)/4)}{\zeta-1}.$$
As $|\zeta^{n+1}|=1$, this sequence is bounded, so that $n^{-1/2}S_n\to0$.

Comment: Thank you. The only thing that I dont understand yet is why $|\zeta^{n+1}|=1$ is enough for it to converge. Shouldn't it be smaler than $1$?

Comment: $(S_n)$ is bounded, $S_n/\sqrt n\to0$. @lolan496